# Passing parameters to Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

In my Rails 4.2.1 app I have `Posts` and `Comments` (which are nested within `Posts`):

```rb
   # config/routes.rb

   resources :posts do
      resources :comments
   end
```

I have the following Comments partial:

```rb
   # app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb

   <%= comment.body %>
```

I'm trying to render that partial from within a `Posts` view:

```rb
   # app/views/posts/show.html.erb

   <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
     <%= render 'comments/comment', :locals => { :comment => comment } %>
   <% end %>
```

The problem is that I'm getting an *undefined local variable or method "comment"* error when trying to render the partial.

I'm pretty new to Rails but it looks to me like I am passing the `comment` variable to the partial correctly. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

**Update**

I was looking in the wrong spot in the documentation. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

[image]

Comment: `# app/views/comments/_form.html.erb` was this a typo?

Comment: Yes... sorry, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either add in `partial`

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', :locals => { :comment => comment } %>
```

Or render the collection:
This does it via rails using the model name

```
<%= render @comments %>
```

Or explicitly

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @comments %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing variables via `locals` hash is not supported in the shorthand syntax of rendering a partial. In that case you can use this one:

```
<%= render 'comments/comment', :comment => comment  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the short hand method for rendering partials. This is more preferred as you do not have to specify the other options.

```
 <%= render 'comments/comment', { :comment => comment } %>
```

Read this URL to learn more;  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html